# Conditionally add attribute that requires an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-typescript, tsx

I'm using Material UI's '[Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)' and it has this attribute `defaultValue` to specify the preselected items in a multiple choice combo box.

This is the code I have:

```
{showDTPicker &&
 <Autocomplete
  multiple
  onChange={(_, newValues) => {
   setSelectedDatatables(newValues)
  }}
  id="combo-box-tables"
  options={datatables}
  defaultValue={selectedDatatables}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.name}
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option?.name === value?.name}
  style={{width: 300, marginRight: '10px'}}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Select datatable" variant="outlined"/>}
 />
}
```

This is a box used to update some fields, so it has to read the current fields (`selectedDatatables`) and then update the state (`setSelectedDatables`) to save them.

Sometimes, though, some of the objects don't have any field set and so `selectedDatatables` is `null`. This breaks the component as the `defaultValue` attribute **expects an array** of something.

How can I use this attribute only when `selectedDatatable` is not null?

The project is in TS/TSX, and `selectedDatatables` is an array and its elements are of type `datatable` (which is then an object with other fields like name and content).

The `showDTPicker` is a state value that shows the component when is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the prop as :

```
defaultValue={selectedDatatables || []}
```

Comment: That was quick. Thank you!